# How Do I Use Localization (i18n) with Haml in Middleman

Tags: localization, internationalization, haml, middleman

The examples on Middleman's web page are in ERB, but I like to use HAML.

http://middlemanapp.com/advanced/localization/

This is their example localization YAML file:

```
---
es:
  hello: "Hola"
```

And this is how they use ERB to access it.

```
<%= I18n.t(:hello) %> World
```

But I prefer HAML to ERB.  How does the above line translate into HAML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would simply be :

```
= I18n.t(:hello)
World
```

You might want to put the greeting in your localization file though :

```
es:
  hello: "Hola %{name}"
```

and call it from your HAML like this

```
= I18n.t(:hello, :name => 'World')
```

Comment: You can also use = t :hello